# Cannot save using register_setting

Tags: options, customization

I am adding an option field to the 'general options' page in WordPress. I cannot get WordPress to save the field. Cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
function add_banner_options() {
    register_setting( 'home_banner_group', 'home_banner' );
    add_settings_field( 'home_banner', 'Home Banner', 'banner_callback', 'general' );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_banner_options' );


function banner_callback( $args ) {
    $val = get_option( 'home_banner' );
    ?>
    <input id="home_banner" type="text" class="regular-text" name="home_banner" value="<?php echo $val; ?>"/>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the codex the group is implied to be unique. However, since I am adding this field to the general options menu, it is in fact this group I must use.

```
 register_setting( 'general', 'home_banner' );
```